# Are there any techniques to organise a Meteor project?

Tags: meteor

Are there any techniques/guides to better organise (modularise) a Meteor project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor is very flexible this way, you can use your own subpackages via meteorite like Thierry said. My favorite way is to just split up my functionality and the stuff that goes inside `<template>` into multiple html files and js files. One for each view/template e.g

```
client/
 home.html (contains my html data in a <template name="home"> and any subtemplates
 home.js (contains my helpers & event handlers for home)
server
 server_methods.js (methods) 
 server_publish.js (publish functions)
```

And for more generic stuff like (`router.js` - for meteor router) I let them stand on their own. Its very convenient meteor just gathers these all up without telling it to and just sends them to the client.

Comment: I agree with this. Just remember that Meteor loads files in a certain order. Folders are loaded in this order: /lib -> /client -> /server -> /public, files are loaded alphabetically and in case of subfolders deeper files are loaded first. So make sure that js files being loaded early dont depend on later files (i.e. load your collections early).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but I plan to try meteorite packages as git/mercurial submodules to my main project.